# Docker-Compose can't connect to Docker Daemon

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, docker, docker-compose

I am getting an error message saying I can't connect to the docker daemon.  I have looked into other people's answers who have had similar issues but it hasn't helped.  I am running the version of Ubuntu 15.10.  I will try to provide all the info I have.

```
root@# docker-compose -f docker-compose-deps.yml up -d
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Docker Version

```
root@# sudo docker     version
Client:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:20:08 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Docker-Compose Version

```
root@# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
```

This is what happens if I try to stop or start the service...

```
root@# sudo service docker stop
stop: Unknown instance: 
root@# sudo service   docker start
docker start/running, process 5375
```

If I run `ps aux | grep docker`

```
root@# ps aux | grep docker
root      4233  0.0  0.0  13692  2204 pts/15   S+   10:27   0:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you may need anymore information.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found this and it seemed to fix my issue.

[GitHub Fix Docker Daemon Crash](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1822)

I changed the content of my docker-compose-deps.yml file as seen in the link.  Then I ran `docker-compose -f docker-compose-deps.yml up -d`.  Then I changed it back and it worked for some reason.  I didn't have to continue the steps in the link I provided, but the first two steps fixed the issue for me.

Comment: ubuntu 16.04  : just add sudo: sudo docker-compose up -d

Comment: It’s not enough as an answer. If you want to accept your own answer, you must put up the very root reason of your issue. Otherwise, it would be a real misleading for others. BTW, there are other answers here, did they help? Since I did not see any comments by you.

Answer (score 552):

I had the same error, after 15 min of debugging. Turns out all it needs is a `sudo` :)

Check out [Manage Docker as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) to get rid of the sudo prefix.

Comment: They need a better error =/ This question has 13,000 views

Comment: the real fix is creating the docker group, while the `sudo` is just a workaround/hack, in my opinion. as the group creating part is not explained here, only a link is given, and the content of that link changed, i consider this a link-only-answer, and it is now essentially useless (for the real fix part). could you maybe add the description of how to add that group?

Comment: I think ``sudo`` is a bad idea as well.  See the Docker docs for managing Docker as a non-root user: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: Basically, all you need to do is `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`, and it will work afterwards.

Comment: Worked for me with Win10 + vagrant + hyperv!

Comment: Don't forget this:Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the virtual machine for changes to take effect.

On a desktop Linux environment such as X Windows, log out of your session completely and then log back in.

Comment: @Jonathan About 60K now!

Answer (score 170):

I had this problem and did not want to mess things up using `sudo`. When investigating, I tried to get some info :

```
docker info
```

Surprinsingly, I had the following error :

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.38/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

For some reason I did not have enough privileges, the following command solved my problem :

```
sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

Et voilà !

Comment: How about after restarting docker again? We have to do this chown again?

Comment: No, it should work when you restart docker. But I'm not sure what happens if you restart your machine.

Comment: By default, Docker would hold `docker.sock` with a non-root group, `docker` as default. But we could change that by `-G` flag during Docker daemon’s initiating. In my case, I add a group for `$USERNAME`, means add docker group, then reboot my machine(ubuntu 16.04, PC). It works well. And this is recommended in docs of docker.

Comment: Works for me too :)

Comment: Have to do this after each reboot :(

Comment: @Adam as mentioned in [Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/), you can solve this with (1st) `sudo groupadd docker` then (2) `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

Comment: OK answer, but `sudo docker-compose up` is much simpler, I think. Note: in order to see what `sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock` does, both before and after the `chown` command I ran `ls -l /var/run/docker.sock`. - Result _before_: . `srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Oct 29 06:39 /var/run/docker.sock` . - Result _after_: . `srw-rw---- 1 ubuntu docker 0 Oct 29 06:39 /var/run/docker.sock` . **Conclusion:** the `chown` command changed the owner of `/var/run/docker.sock` from `root` to `$USER` (in my case `ubuntu`). New problem: `fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux[...]` seemingly takes forever. SIGH!

Comment: nice solution in my problem

Answer (score 44):

It appears your issue was created by an old Docker bug, where the socket file was not recreated after Docker crashed. If this is the issue, then renaming the socket file should allow it to be re-created:

```
$ sudo service docker stop
$ sudo mv /var/lib/docker /var/lib/docker.bak
$ sudo service docker start
```

Since this bug is fixed, most people getting the error `Couldn't connect to Docker daemon` are probably getting it because they are not in the `docker` group and don't have permissions to read that file.  Running with `sudo docker ...` will fix that, but isn't a great solution.

Docker can be run as a non-root user (without `sudo`) that has the proper group permissions. The [Linux post-install docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) has the details. The short version:

```
$ sudo groupadd docker
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
# Log out and log back in again to apply the groups
$ groups  # docker should be in the list of groups for your user
$ docker run hello-world  # Works without sudo
```

This allows users in the `docker` group to run `docker` and `docker-compose` commands without `sudo`. Docker itself runs a root, allowing some attacks, so you still need to be careful with what containers you run. See [Docker Security Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) for more details.

Comment: This question is specific to the Linux install, and the fix involves changes on the Linux host system to fix it. You'll get better information if you post a similar question with the same detail but for Windows. To solve yourself, I recommend a close reading of the [Docker for Windows documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue. After taking notes and analyzing some debugging results, finally, I solved what can be the same error. Start the service first,

`service docker start`

Don't forget to include your user to the docker group.

Comment: I was running as root when I encountered this error. Seemed like `sudo` fixed it for others -_-
Glad to find that it was indeed this, that I forgot to do. So simple!

Answer (score 13):

just try with `sudo`. It seems like permission issue!

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-deps.yml up -d
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

One way to resolve this would be to first add your user to the `docker` group by running the following

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

IMPORTANT: Remember to log out of your system (not just your terminal) and back in for this to take effect!

Comment: sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}


We should also logout & login to apply changes:
su - ${USER}

Answer (score 11):

You should adding your user to the "docker" group with something like:

> sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}

Answer (score 9):

in my case it is because the ubuntu permission,

1. List item

check permission by

```
docker info
```

if they print problem permission,
[image]
 then use

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: "chmod 777" is never the correct solution. If it is, you have one-in-a-thousand exception that confirms this rule.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error when there were files in the `Dockerfile` directory that were not accessible by the current user. `docker` could thus not upload the full context to the daemon and brought the "*Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket*" message.

Comment: Thanks! This solved it for me. Easy to check, since all docker commands worked, but docker-compose did not. Also docker-compose worked in another directory. Very misleading error message, BTW.

Comment: This should really be higher up

Comment: Thanks! worked for me. Using `docker build .` will yield any permission problems.

Comment: Only thing that worked - why are Docker error messages so bad? Thanks!

Comment: this solved my problem too. when I checked my folders, I saw some files/folders that is owned by another user. once I fixed the issue by chowning file's user/group, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the output of "ps aux | grep docker", it looks like docker daemon is not running. Try using below methods to see what is wrong and why docker is not starting

1. Check the docker logs

$ sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/docker.log

2. Try starting docker in debug mode

$ sudo docker -d -D

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why this error can show up: for me it was a malformed image-path definition in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  service:
    image: ${CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE}/my-service
   ...
```

Lookis ok'ish first, but i had `CONTAINER_REGISTRY_BASE=eu.gcr.io/my-project/` set on the env. Apparently the `//` in the image path caused this error.

```
docker-compose: v.1.21.2
docker: 18.03.1-ce
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case your docker service might be stopped

Command to start docker service:

`$ sudo systemctl start docker`

Command to verify if it start:

`$ sudo docker run hello-world`

Answer (score 2):

I used Ubuntu 16.04 and found this problem too when I used docker-compose.
I fixed it by running this command.

```
$ sudo systemctl start docker
$ sudo docker-compose build
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there slight possibility you deleted default machine?
But, first check if all files are there (OSX, similar on other systems)

```
brew install docker docker-compose docker-machine xhyve docker-machine-driver-xhyve
brew link docker docker-compose docker-machine xhyve docker-machine-driver-xhyve

sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/opt/docker-machine-driver-xhyve/bin/docker-machine-driver-xhyve
```

Also, install Docker App, as it much easier to maintain containers:

```
brew cask reinstall docker
```

ans start Docker app from finder (wait until service is fully started)

Then, check instalation with:

```
docker-machine ls
```

if no machines are present in list, create one and start it:

```
docker-machine create default
docker-machine start default
```

After this, build, compose and all other commands should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Final Solution:**
First run this command: sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
Then run this command: docker-compose up -d --build

Answer (score 0):

In my case a have the same error when I try to `docker-compose build`
and my solution was just add `sudo`

```
sudo docker-compose build
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was to install a newer version (1.24) of `docker-compose` using [this article](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

The previous version (1.17) was installed from `ubuntu`'s default repository, but after installing a newer version I managed to launch the container. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of right of access, you just have to write

```
sudo docker-compose-deps.yml up
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was with the inappropriate image tag name `-backend` - started with a short leading dash:

**FAILED:**

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my.backend
    image: imagename:-backend
    build:
      context: .
```

Error message:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

**WORKS:**    with `my-backend`

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my.backend
    image: imagename:my-backend
    build:
      context: .
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to `sudo chown -Rv someuser.someuser ~someuser/docker_compose_dir/`, where `someuser` is the user I run `docker-compose` under. After that, `docker-compose` went smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Worth adding here that if you have docker-desktop installed you can run:

```
docker context list
```

This should give you the docker url for the engine running with docker-desktop.
You can then set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable for compose to use.
In my case it was by adding it at the bottom of `~/.bashrc`:

```
export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///home/rouanubuntu/.docker/desktop/docker.sock"
```

This points docker-compose to the engine running with the desktop UI which is useful.

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` or relogin to load it.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a missing environment variable - reading the WARNING actually helped.. In case it also helps somebody else:

`docker-compose.yml:`

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  app:
    image: my/app:${BUILD}
    build:
      args:
        GIT_BUILD_INFO: ${GIT_BUILD_INFO}
```

Bash history in Ubuntu 20.04 to replicate the issue:

```
$ docker-compose -p energycontrol -f docker-compose-jenkins.yml build

WARNING: The BUILD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The GIT_BUILD_INFO variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building app
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

```
$ sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-06-20 11:31:14 CEST; 4min 9s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 2504 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 56
     Memory: 268.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─2504 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Jun 20 11:31:30 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:31:30.901226992+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:31:35 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:31:35.860433546+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:31:43 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:31:43.235052163+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:31:53 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:31:53.702991779+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:32:08 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:32:08.434441406+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:32:35 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:32:35.534456987+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:33:28 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:33:28.203608203+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:34:30 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:34:30.647314927+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=1c188fbed9835609677392e4e8ab14f0d0ffefce0cb5ed29362377c05c3ffc67 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jun 20 11:34:46 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:34:46.218537851+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.35/build returned error: invalid reference format"
Jun 20 11:35:12 dozer dockerd[2504]: time="2023-06-20T11:35:12.058911161+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.35/build returned error: invalid reference format"
```

After setting the environment variables, everything worked out:

```
$ export BUILD="temp"
$ export GIT_BUILD_INFO="something"
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
Building app
[...]
Successfully built f0b57a1cfbaa
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was different. I was able to easily replicate it on another machine as well as running as root, hence no problem with docker.

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx_service:
    build: .
    image: Service/nginx_service
```

This is what I found in syslog:

```
Oct 24 08:20:50 build0 dockerd: time="2023-10-24T08:20:50.665225676+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.25/build returned error: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase"
```

Someone used a capital letter in the image name.

```
# diff docker-compose.yml.old docker-compose.yml
5c5
<     image: Service/nginx_service
---

>     image: service/nginx_service
```

**The fix: use lower case letters in docker-compose.yml.**